# Cross join or full join in LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I stumbled upon this LINQ query while reading a book.

```
var binary = new int[] { 0, 1 };

var q = from b4 in binary
        from b3 in binary
        from b2 in binary
        from b1 in binary
        select String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", b4, b3, b2, b1);

foreach (var element in q)
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

The result of the above LINQ will be

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

I wanted to see how this will be in SQL Server.

What I have tried:

```
create table LINQ(x bit)
insert LINQ select 0
insert LINQ select 1

create table LINQ(x bit, y bit)
insert LINQ select 0,1
```

I tried using LINQPAD (does not give the SQL or lambda version), using the above temp tables. I tried cross join, full join. I did not get the SQL which gives the same result as LINQ.

Comment: You must be really obsessed with ones and zeroes, given your user name.  In any case, while Linq may seem to be a proxy for SQL, it really isn't.  Linq works over *any collection,* not just tables.

Comment: @85: Which username is Robert Harvey talking about?

Comment: @Robert Harvey really obsessed with ones and zeroes :) No just coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(l1.x as varchar(4)) + CAST(l2.x as varchar(4))+ CAST(l3.x as varchar(4)) + CAST(l4.x as varchar(4))
FROM LINQ as l1, LINQ as l2, LINQ as l3, LINQ as l4
ORDER BY l1.x, l2.x, l3.x, l4.x
```

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b1daf/4)

Comment: I don't think this will produce the expected output.

Comment: yes that does not give the desired result as Robert mentioned

Comment: Doesn't it?  Check the sqlfiddle - where is it different?

Comment: @1010101: Check the SQLFiddle

Comment: @1010101: 01101110011011110010000001110000011100100110111101100010011011000110010101101101